# RAD complains that projects are missing library files but they are present in .classpath

Tags: classpath, rad

In my RAD, often times when I launch it and go to my workspace, i see some projects have a red error cross sign. And usually the message is that certain libraries are missing etc. But by going to the build path of each project, I can see that the libraries are existing in the build path.

This issue I have been solving by removing the library that RAD is complaining about,building the project, adding the library back and building the project again.Then the error goes away. It seems that RAD somehow loses track of the libraries. The .classpath file however shows that the library exists even though RAD was complaining.

Is there a permanent fix to this issue?

Answer (score 5):

This is a known RAD problem and has been reported many times.
Go to each "broken" project, right-click and select "JavaEE -> Update EAR Libraries" and the errors should go away.
Closing & reopening the project(s) in question, then cleaning & rebuilding the workspace, will also help.